# Exclude single characters from rle output?

Tags: java, compression

```
    public static String compress(String original) {
    StringBuffer dest = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
        int runLength = 1;
        while (i+1 < original.length() && original.charAt(i) == original.charAt(i+1)) {
            runLength++;
            i++;
        }
        dest.append(runLength);
        dest.append(original.charAt(i));
    }
    return dest.toString();
}
```

hello all, so i have this code block for a method to compress a phrase using RLE algorithm. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the method exclude applying RLE compression to single characters in my output.

At the moment, if the user enters "fffgggttth", then the code outputs "3f3g3t1h", but I want the output to leave the h alone, so it would just be "3f3g3th".

I feel like the solution involves a break or continue statement before the for block, but I could be wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trivial answer to your problem:

```
if(runLength > 1) dest.append(runLength);
```

Simply put, it will only add the number of continuous occurrences of a character if it appears more than once. If the character appears only one time in a row, it will not append the length (which is 1). Make sure you take into account 1's not appearing in your decompression method.

Comment: when you say making sure 1's not appearing, do you mean adding an error condition that if the amount its going to be compressed to is 1, having it ignore the operation?

Comment: For example, 'aaabcc' will compress to '3ab2c'. When decompressing, '3a' will mean replace with 'aaa', 'b' without a number in front of it will mean leave it as one 'b', and '2c' will be replaced with 'cc'. Just make sure you have a case if there is no number directly in front of a character, assume it is just one occurrence of that character.